# Is there a way to insert a manual approval for Build pipeline 1.5.8 version in jenkins 2

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins 2.89.2 version.

For deployment into production system it's often useful to require manual approval; is there a way to insert a manual button to press inside a pipeline?

I tried using **Build other Project(manual Step)** in post build action but still i don't see any approval button or manual intervention at prod build in build pipeline..
And as i can see that In **Build pipeline ---> Manually trigger downstream projects**  is no more avail in Build pipeline version 1.5.8.

Can anyone help on this how to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: use the [input step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) in your Pipeline like so:

```
input(message: "Proceed with this build?")
```